# Quando são atualizados os pacotes de tradução, messages.eng.txt, messages.spa.txt do Genexus?

Tags: genexus

Quando são atualizados os pacotes de tradução? Com o *Build all* ou com o *Build with this* de alguns objetos envolvidos?

Porque estamos trabalhando como  GX Translator Tool separado da nossa KB.

E quando será atualizada as strings na KB de produção? Com BUILD ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que os objetos Language da KB tenham as mensagens (existentes nos objetos) incorporadas, é requerido um Build All.
Cuando um objeto Language é modificado (seja por Import ou Save normal), é somente necessário um Build do objeto Main em questão para que os recursos (messages.*.txt,etc) sejam gerados e assim a aplicação tenha as traduções incluídas.